# Creating dynamic labels from access DB in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

### Creating dynamic labels from access DB in vb.net

Ok so i have a Database have some players info and i want to create a label for each player in the database and since the number of players is not static i put a code there to create a label for each record in my database everything works fine and all BUT the first record in the database never show up for some reason and if i put a break point its always starts from the 2nd record so this is my code so far and i really don't know what i'm doing wrong there everything looks fine to me, thank you in advanced.

```
Public Class PostionManagement
    Dim Dragging As Boolean

    Private Sub NewPlayerslabel()
        Try
            Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\HHDB.accdb;")
            Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
            con.Open()
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, PlayerName, PlayerClass,PlayerRule FROM PlayersDB WHERE (PlayerRule = 'Static')"
            cmd.Prepare()
            Dim Players = cmd.ExecuteReader
            With Players.Read()
                Dim PosX As Integer = 25
                For Each item In Players
                    Dim NewPlayer As New Label
                    NewPlayer.Name = item("ID")
                    NewPlayer.Location = New Point(12, PosX)
                    PosX += 25
                    NewPlayer.Text = item("PlayerName") & " (" & item("PlayerClass") & ")"
                    NewPlayer.Width = 200
                    NewPlayer.BackColor = Color.Transparent
                    If item("PlayerClass") = "Brawler" Or item("PlayerClass") = "Lancer" Then
                        NewPlayer.ForeColor = Color.Blue
                    ElseIf item("PlayerClass") = "Mystic" Or item("PlayerClass") = "Priest" Then
                        NewPlayer.ForeColor = Color.Green
                    Else
                        NewPlayer.ForeColor = Color.Red
                    End If
                    NewPlayer.Visible = True
                    AddHandler NewPlayer.MouseDown, AddressOf Newplayer_MouseDown
                    AddHandler NewPlayer.MouseUp, AddressOf Newplayer_MouseUp
                    AddHandler NewPlayer.MouseMove, AddressOf Newplayer_MouseMove
                    Me.Controls.Add(NewPlayer)
                Next
            End With
            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub Newplayer_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
        Dragging = True
    End Sub
    Private Sub Newplayer_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
        Dragging = False
    End Sub
    Private Sub Newplayer_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
        If Dragging = True Then
            Dim Point As Point
            Dim LableName As Control = CType(sender, Control)
            Point = Me.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
            LableName.Top = Point.Y
            LableName.Left = Point.X
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub PostionManagement_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        NewPlayerslabel()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
With Players.Read()
    Dim PosX As Integer = 25
    For Each item In Players
```

I think what you were trying to get at is this:

```
Dim PosX As Integer = 25
While Players.Read()
```

Comment: this solved it ty. also had to change `item` to `Players` for the code to fully work.